# How to receive PROVIDERS_CHANGED broadcast in Android Oreo

Tags: android-broadcast, android-8.0-oreo

Apps handle GeoFence needs to receive `PROVIDERS_CHANGED` broadcast since:

1. Registered GeoFences will be removed when both 2 location providers
   (network and GPS) are turned off.
2. When one of 2 location providers is turned on, app needs to register
   GeoFences to work. This should be performed w/o asking user to run
   my app again.

So my app has been registering its broadcast receiver in manifest. But it does not work any more in Android Oreo since `PROVIDERS_CHANGED` is not one we can make it work as before.

I can register broadcast receiver for that in app's activity or in service but it will quit (end its life cycle) sooner or later, then I need to unregister it. My app starts working by some events like GeoFence transition, but receiving `PROVIDERS_CHANGED` is critical to make it work.

I verified `PROVIDERS_CHANGED` can't be received by receiver registered in manifest in Android Oreo. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: any update? any solution?

Comment: @Virat18, I coud not find good way to solve this and it seems checking location provider state peridodically by using alarm manager is the only way to detect 'changes' so far.

Comment: I too am facing this issue.. In my case, I only require to know when the Location toggle gets turned ON in Settings. Unfortunately I've had no luck. I'll continue searching and will favorite this post to let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: @Tomcat did you manage to find out the solution?

Answer (score 1):

@Tomcat and @Virat18 - I've come across a solution to the fact that you can no longer register a Broadcast Receiver in your Manifest to receive the `PROVIDERS_CHANGED` action Intent-filter in Android-OREO..

The solution? Simply register your `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically (from within your code), instead of from the Manifest.. Also, instead of checking for the hard-coded regex `android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED`, you should use `LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION` (and of course import the `LocationManager`).

**Here is an example of the Code I used to get this to work! (ex: from a Button Click):**

```
public void buttonClick(View view) {

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED");

    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().matches(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Action MATCHES LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION!");
            }
        }
    };

    this.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    Log.i(TAG, "RECEIVER HAS BEEN REGISTERED");

}
```

Also, don't forget to *unregister* the receiver in your code appropriately.

If you find this to be a good solution, please **accept it as the Answer**.
**Happy Coding!**

PS. This will continue to receive the broadcast from the background, even once the User leaves your Activity (presses the back-button, home-button, etc).. However, if the user closes your App from the Multitask button, it will no longer receive, so take note of that.

Comment: My app needs to be notified when location provider state was changed even my app/service is not active. I think Google has removed a way to achieve that at Oreo. Solution you provided is unfortunatley not sufficient to my case. Google may have not paid attention to apps which needs to register geofences again when location provider is backed on.

Comment: @Tomcat The example I provided will tell you when the Location setting has become available (once you add the LocationManager code to check for GPS availability).. And if true, you can (as of Oreo) use the Google API's to register for your callbacks to receive the Location, even in the background (although it has been limited more so than previously).

Comment: Thank you for providing solution but that won't meet my requirement.

Comment: I tried also exactly as you suggested above in your answer, but I didn't even reach the `onReceive` event in the code. I use android compileSdkVersion: 28. buildToolsVersion: 28.0.3. minSdkVersion: 21 (for androidx).